# SSH: connection refused - Server started but sshd not running?

Tags: ssh

I can't connect to my Raspbery Pi over SSH any more. The last lines that appear on booting are:

```
[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
Error opening '/dev/input/event*': No such file or directory
```

(btw: what is `/dev/input/event*`?)

But when I try to connect to my Raspberry Pi, I get this:

```
$ ssh user@raspberrypi
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 22: Connection refused
```

I found out that there is a problem with the SSH Daemon. `ps aux |grep sshd` does not list it as a process. Once I start it manually

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

SSH works well and I can connect with the command above. But soon as I reboot and try it again, I get the same error message.

I already tried to reinstall the openssh-server and then reinstall it. That didn't help. Does someone have a solution?

Comment: is anything plugged into the Pi like a usb keyboard/mouse? if so try unplugging it/them before continuing.

Comment: That was it. I unplugged the keyboard, restarted the Pi and it worked. Unbelievable...

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/input/event*` [is](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) what it sounds like; a place for applications to receive input events (like a mouse click). As @rob noted the USB interface on the raspberrypi is somewhat unstable so not using it (or using a power isolated powered hub) are good first steps to otherwise inexplicable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To start sshd on boot, type :

```
sudo update-rc.d ssh defaults
```